# Uso de parênteses após a declaração da função Javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender o que significa essa sintaxe na declaração de uma função em JavaScript. Estou usando um plugin que declara uma função e após a chave de fechamento da declaração da função é incluído o parênteses () antes do ;

```
var myFunction = function () {

...

}();
```

Comment: Isso é uma técnica chamada **IIFE**, pode saber mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa questão do parênteses, é para que sua função seja executada assim que for lida pelo script.

Se você fizer:

```
var myFunction = function () {

     console.log('ok')

}();
```

Verá que no terminal, apenas com esse código será impresso "ok", sem a necessidade de lá na frente chamar o valor executado o pela função contida na variável `myFunction()`.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado!